# Unsetting the Fn key in emacs on console

Tags: emacs, elisp, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using emacs24 on a laptop with no X org, only theLlinux console. The laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad. When I hit <kbd>Fn</kbd> (that I use in various combos to adjust volume, brightness etc.) the selection mark is set similarly as when I hit `C-SPC`. That's impractical as I would like to change volume without selecting text.

Checking with `C-h k <kbd>Fn</kbd>` in emacs I get exactly the same output as when pressing `C-h k C-SPC`:

```
C-@ runs the command set-mark-command, which is an interactive compiledLisp function.
It is bound to C-@, C-SPC.

(set-mark-command ARG)
...
```

Checking with `$ acpi_listen` pressing `C-SPC`, <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and `C-@` all gives me the same output: `^@`. In other words, they're all interpreted as the same acpi event.

I can unset `C-@` with:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-@") 'ignore)
```

But that prevents `C-SPC` from working as well and in combination with the above I can't re-set it by:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") 'set-mark-command)
```

Meanwhile if i use `$ showkey` i get: `keycode 143 press` and `keycode 143 release` from pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

What elisp code could make emacs distinguish between `C-SPC` and <kbd>Fn</kbd> and enable me to unset the latter without unsetting the former?

Comment: If acpi_listen reports the same values for each key, there's no way Emacs will be able to distinguish them. Emacs can only use the information the operating system gives it, and it's the OS that's wrong here. I think you need to check into xmodmap to straighten this out outside of Emacs.

Comment: I don't have X org server installed on the laptop - online the console. Will xmodmap work? Or would it make sense to look into /etc/inputrc instead?

Comment: sorry, missed that you are just in a console. xmodmap requires X. I'm not sure what to use instead :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments the problem doesn't pertain to emacs specifically. This solution using dumpkeys, loadkeys and showkey is likely to work in other instances of function keys getting interpreted in unexpected ways by programs running in the Linux Virtual Console.

Find the keycode of the key or key combo causing trouble by running:

```
 $ sudo showkey
```

... and hitting the key. In my instance hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd> gave the output 143.

To stop <kbd>Fn</kbd> from being interpreted as anything by programs in the console, add this /etc/rc.local:

> (dumpkeys | grep keymaps; echo "keycode 143 =") | loadkeys

143 should of course be replaced by the keycode of the relevant key in question. I also had a problem with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> (meant for volume down) outputting a tilde, so I got the code for that combo as well, and threw in another line for with that in /etc/.

Note that this doesn't prevent the normal behavior of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> functions (changing volume, brightness etc.) it only prevents function keys from being interpreted as anything by programs like emacs.